# SQL: Trigger set column to null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I created a trigger to set a column to null where the column has a value greater than `GETDATE()`

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Null_Time_Trigger3]

  on [dbo].[Parking]
  FOR insert
  as
  update Parking
  set Column = NULL
  from Parking
  where Column >= CAST(GETDATE () AS TIME)
```

it appears when the time passes the trigger doesn't do anything? the time is still in the column and the column is not having the value of `NULL`.

Any idea how to resolve this ??

Is there anyway to do this `(Setting the column to null) other than triggers???`

Regards.

Comment: Your trigger is raised when you insert a record, so what does it means _when the time passes_?

Comment: @Marco The column is having a value of time ok? when the `system time` `(GETDATE)` is greater than the time in the `column`, the trigger should set that `Column` to `NULL`

Comment: First of all, I think you should use < in your trigger definition. Anyway this trigger is fired **ONLY** when you insert a new row in db and acts **ONLY** on that row, not on previous ones!!!

Comment: This is not what triggers are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I think you should use < in your trigger definition. Anyway this trigger is fired **ONLY** when you insert a new row in db and acts **ONLY** on that row, not on previous ones!!!
You could do that with one query:

```
UPDATE Parking SET `Column`=NULL
WHERE `Column` < CAST(GETDATE () AS TIME)
```

**EDITED:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Null_Time_Trigger4]
on [dbo].[Parking]
FOR INSERT,UPDATE
AS BEGIN
    UPDATE Parking SET `Column`=NULL
    WHERE `Column` < CAST(GETDATE () AS TIME)
END
```

Comment: @Marco: even when the row with a time less than the GETDATE() it does not change it to NULL, is there anyway to do this other than a trigger ?

Comment: @Marco: can i make the query launch automatically ?

Comment: @Humam Shbib: if you use an app (written in C# for example) you could create a Timer that executes every second this query...
Or you can insert a trigger in db that everytime a row is added executes this other query too...

Comment: @Marco: and how is the second option is possible ?

Comment: @Humam Shbib: I don't know if the trigger in my edited post works, but should do what you need everytime you insert/update a row in Parking table.

Comment: This update all rows in the Parking table. Why not use INSERTED?

Answer (score 3):

`insert` triggers only fire on an insert statement. If there is no `insert` operation your trigger will not run.

As your trigger references the `Parking` table itself rather than the `inserted` table it might work on insert but this is totally not what triggers are for.

There are no temporal triggers in SQL Server that would automatically `NULL`-ify the columns when the time is passed (as it seems you might be expecting).

You can do `CASE WHEN Column < CAST(GETDATE () AS TIME) THEN Column END AS Column` in your `SELECT` instead.

Comment: Same time: your answer is the same as my comment :)

Comment: @Martin yeah the row which i want to set to null is inserted is actually having a value

Comment: @Martin: is there anyway to do this other than a trigger ?

Comment: @Humam - If you need to set the column to null after the time value it contains has elapsed you could use SQL Agent to schedule a job that runs periodically and does this or you could use Service Broker - Possibly this last option would allow you to set up a more sophisticated system where the process only runs when required, not sure about that. Is it really necessary to Nullify the columns? Can't your relevant code just check whether the `column < getdate()`?

Comment: @Martin: since the nature of my system is a parking reservation, they have to be null so that the parking lots could be available again.

Comment: @Human - But your code that allocates parking slots could just recognize that they are available if either the column is NULL or the value in the column has expired.

Comment: @Martin: what if all the slots in the database do not satisfy the SQL statement assigned with the web app ?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a calculated column, something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE
(
...
Column  DATETIME,
CurrentColumn  AS CASE WHEN DATETIME < SYSDATETIME() THEN DATETIME END
....
)
```

However, in general you should log events as new records rather than updating an existing column.  Your current design destroys information.